# CGContextDrawImage containing only intersection of two images

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, bitmap

Since CGContextDrawImage can be quite expensive, I'm trying to minimize the amount of data I'm giving it while I examine the pixel data. If I have two images and the CGRect of their intersection, can I get CGContextDrawImage to only draw the intersection of each independently (resulting in two CGContextRefs containing the intersection of one of the images)?

Here's some code that doesn't work, but should be close to what I need for one image...

```
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = rectIntersect.size.width;
    NSUInteger height = rectIntersect.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // rectIntersect down here contains the intersection of the two images...
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rectIntersect, imageRef);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you don't need to draw them unless you really want a `CGBitmapContext` with them.  Use `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()` to create sub-images.  This doesn't necessarily require the frameworks to copy any image data.  It may just reference the image data from the original.  So, it can be quite efficient.

If you really do need the images drawn into contexts, you can of course just draw the sub-images.

Comment: The reason I'm drawing them to a CGBitmapContext is because I need to save the coordinates of certain color or alpha pixels. I don't actually need to display the drawn results on the screen, though. Is there a way to access the individual pixel data from the original without the CGBitmapContext?

Comment: [Technical Q&A QA1509: Getting the pixel data from a CGImage object](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1509/_index.html)

Comment: CGImageCreateWithImageInRect is exactly what I was looking for - The additional link you provided also helped simplify my code. Thanks!